# MYSQL sum but if a value is change value to add to sum

Tags: mysql

I'm thinking of a way to sum a column but if one of the rows has an 02 or 03 in there the charge to sum is not what is shown and should be changed.

SELECT serial, email, SUM(charge) as amountpayable From billings where charge > '0' GROUP BY email.

This displays as intended but for instance if column type is equal to 02 or 03 I need to change the charge field from .10 to .50 and if the type field is equal to 04 or 05 I need to change the charge field from .20 to .80 for the sum to some out correctly.

I'm not quite up to speed on IF statements in MySQL but guessing that would be the way.

Comment: Unclear.  Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the changes can be done with `case`-`when`:

```
SELECT serial,
       email,
       SUM(
           CASE
               WHEN `type` IN ('02', '03') THEN charge + 0.40
               WHEN `type` IN ('04', '05') THEN charge + 0.60
               ELSE charge
           END
       ) AS amountpayable
FROM billings
WHERE charge > '0'
GROUP BY email
```

In the above I assume that

- you have a `type` field
- your `type` field is textual
- your `charge` is numeric
- in case of 02 or 03 `type`, `charge` + 0.40 (.50 - .10) is the correct charge
- in case of 04 or 05 `type`, `charge` + 0.60 (.80 - .20) is the correct value
- for other types `charge` is good as it is

If my understanding described above is wrong about your problem, then please let me know.

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you. exactly what I needed to do for the sum

Comment: @arch691 I'm glad your problem was successfully resolved.